# Why is OleDbDataAdapter needed?

Tags: c#

Everything is possible with the OleDBDataReader class.
ExecuteReader() for SELECT statements, and ExecuteNonQuery() for DELETE, UPDATE and INSERT statements.

So why is OleDbDataAdapter class needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [OleDbDataAdapter Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbdataadapter(VS.71).aspx)

> Represents a set of data commands and
>   a database connection that are **used
>   to fill the DataSet and update the
>   data source.**